# $145^n+3114 \cdot 138^n$ is divisible by $1981$ if $n = 1981$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that the integer $145^n+3114 \cdot 138^n$ is divisible by $1981$ if $n = 1981$, and that it is not divisible by $1981$ if $n = 1980$.

We have $145 = 5 \cdot 29, 3114 = 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 173,$ and $138 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 23$. How do we use this to relate it with $1981$ in order to solve the question?

Comment: Hint:  $3114\equiv1$ mod $145+138=1981/7$.

Comment: We have $145^{1980}+3114\cdot 138^{1980}\equiv 1386\bmod 1981$, which is not congruent to zero. Use $a^p\equiv a$ for primes $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1981=7\cdot 283$, in order to prove that $1981$ is a divisor of $M=145^{1981}+3114\cdot 138^{1981}$
it is enough to prove that $M\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ and $M\equiv 0\pmod{283}$. By Fermat's little theorem, that boils down to showing that
$$ 5^1+6\cdot 5^1 \equiv 0\pmod{7},\qquad (-138)^{7}+138^{7}\equiv 0\pmod{283}, $$
both trivial. In the other case, $1981$ cannot be a divisor of $N=145^{1980}+3114\cdot 138^{1980}$, since
$$ N\equiv (-138)^6+138^6\neq 0 \pmod{283}, $$
always by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: As a side note, $145 \equiv -138 \pmod {283}$

Comment: @Evariste: it is probably better to directly write $145\pmod{283}$ as $-138$. Now updating, thanks for the suggestion.